# Get Calendar id in ICAL calendar while creating Event in java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, icalendar, ical4j

I  am creating a google meeting invite using ical calendar in java. After creating event I need to get or set event id of the created event

Comment: This is not a question, please clarify what your issue is

Comment: currently, i am able to create events in java  using ical calendar  but I a want to get event id for that event after creating it

Comment: Update your question instead of (trying to) post additional information as comments.

Comment: Hi i need to get event id while creating events in ical calander . in java

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Then edit your question showing enough of your code so that we can see the problem. and describe the problem in detail error messages ect.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully creating an event, you will get the [event object](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) as a response. You can read it to get its ID.

If you want to know the ID of a previously created event, you can user the [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method to search for it. You can see on the documentation the multiple fields that you can use for searching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I am creating an event using a ical calendar. in ical how to get event   id for created event